# Importing a Large Dataset in MongoDB via MongoID

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoid, nosql

To import a large JSON dataset in MongoDB we have mongoimport utility which works like that:

```
mongoimport --host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --db destination-db -c tags < tmp/source-file.json
```

Is there a way to call 'mongoimport' using MongoID, the ruby Object-Document-Mapper for MongoDB ?

Thanks
Luca

Comment: Is there a reason you'd want to do that?

Comment: to embody the 'business logic' into rails app, avoiding 'external' shell command to use in crontab or something, which became platform dependent. How would you use mongoimport whith Heroku for example ?

Comment: So, you have an export somewhere (by which process?) and you want to import that using code instead of the utility?

Comment: I'd like to 'get' a json doc, from an external API provider, storing the json directly into MongoDB, using my Rails app with MongoID interface already in place ...

Comment: I'd like to know how to do this as well. In the past I have just executed a system command from within rails (`\`mongoimport\``), but that solution is far from ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoid is effectively a wrapper around the Ruby driver. The Ruby driver should allow you to run any of the database commands.

However, `mongoimport` is not a command. `mongoimport` is a separate binary (or executable) file.

The only way to run `mongoimport` from Ruby is to "shell out". Typically this involves using some form of `exec` command. Here's the first search link for [running shell commands from Ruby](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html).

Comment: Thanks Gates VP very useful article. I finally get the job running system("mongoimport --host localhost --db myDB --collection repo --file tags.json -f repositories")

Answer (score 1):

You can also parse the JSON from your file, and just run `Model.create(json_obj)` and `Mode.save` directly in a rake task.